# VBA Configuração de Referências

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Bom dia, pode ser algo bem besta, mas estou começando a trabalhar com VBA para busca de dados na web e toda vez que começo um projeto novo tenho que adicionar as referências "Microsoft HTML Object Library" e o "Microsoft Internet Controls". Como faço para deixá-las sempre selecionadas?

Abs.

Comment: Há uma maneira de adicionar com código VBA, veja [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880276/7690982). Porém a opção para estar sempre adicionada nas referências eu não encontrei.

Comment: Ok. Obrigado Daniel

Comment: Eu ja tive a necessidade de adicionar outras bibliotecas e utilizei a referencia abaixo: [Adicionado refencia dinamicamente](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/565/adicionando-referencias-dinamicamente-no-vba.aspx) Espero que possa ter ajudado.